# Ajax Working but empty response from AJAX in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I try to code different way but i'm facing same issue, admin-ajax working well but nothing returning, Basically empty response, I just want to what i mass up with,

**My HTML Code**

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url("/") ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="noman_input" name="input_name_sb">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('sb_form');?>
    
    <input id="sub_form"  class="btn btn-danger"  type="submit" value="Post Via Ajax">
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
function form_sb_form(){
    $user_name = $_POST['input_name_sb'];
    echo $user_name;
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_sb_form', 'form_sb_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sb_form', 'form_sb_form');
```

**JS Code**

```
 $("#sub_form").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var user_name = $("#noman_input").val();

            // i try with this code 
            $.ajax({
                url: loc_data.ajax_url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: 'sb_form',
                    name: user_name
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response)
                },
            });

            // and this one as well
            $.post(loc_data.ajax_url, {
                action: "sb_form",
                user_name: user_name,
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        });
```

Comment: add `dataType: 'HTML' ` to your ajax call.

Comment: You need to actually output something to get in the response. The `$user_name` variable can be empty, try something like `echo 'hello world';` to test.

Comment: An empty response in PHP also sometimes means a server error, so check the logs

Answer (score 2):

You target the wrong $_POST key. It should be `name` instead of `input_name_sb`

```
function form_sb_form(){
    $user_name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $user_name;
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment but it should be the text what i put in name property right?

Comment: no, It will be the key name inside data {} object. so it will be $_POST['action'] and $_POST['name']